# multilevel dropdown menu toggle not working using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

First of all let me tell you I'm little weak in jquery so helping here will let me learn lot about jquery.
I'm trying to expand the level 2 li menu using jquery but alas after searching google for a while i'd to post my problem in here. so my problem html skeleton is somewhat like below before that i'm working on wp nav.

```
<div class="mobile-menu">
    <div id="megaMenu">
        <div id="megaMenuToggle"></div>
        <ul id="megaUber>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <ul>
                            <li></li>
                            <li></li>
                            <li></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                   <li></li>
                </ul>
             </li>
             <li></li>
             <li></li>
             <li></li>
         </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

now the problem is i can open the level 1 li in toggle but while opening the level 2 it's not toggling. here is my css code for toggling.

```
.mobile-menu #megaMenu #megaUber > li.active > a + ul {
    display: block !important;}

.mobile-menu #megaMenu #megaUber > li > a + ul {
    display: none !important;}

.mobile-menu #megaMenu #megaUber > li > ul > li.actives > a + ul {
    display: block !important;}
.mobile-menu #megaMenu #megaUber > li > ul > li > a + ul {
    display: none !important}
```

here is the jquery code that i've written which is working for the level 1 li & megaMenuToggle div toggle but not for level 2.

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(".mobile-menu #megaMenu #megaMenuToggle").on('click', function(){
      $(".mobile-menu #megaMenu #megaUber").slideToggle( "slow" );
    });

    $('.mobile-menu #megaMenu #megaUber li a').on('click',function(event){
      console.log('first drop');
      event.stopPropagation();
      $(".mobile-menu #megaMenu #megaUber li")
        .not($(this).parent())
        .removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");

    });

    $('.mobile-menu #megaMenu #megaUber li ul li a').on('click',function(event){
      console.log('second drop');
      event.stopPropagation();
      $("#megaUber li")
        .not($(this).parent())
        .removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");

      $("#megaUber li ul li")
        .not($(this).parent())
        .removeClass("actives");
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("actives");
    });
});
```

Comment: Your HTML seems to lack the classes and ids of your CSS and jQuery. Can you fix that please?

Also, you appear to be using UberMenu? What are you trying to do to it?

Comment: @colepanike sorry but the code is not working I've putted it in the jsfiddle please see if you can give me any solution by this code  http://jsfiddle.net/7d7dow03/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've got a working version: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7d7dow03/2/)

### The Fix:

```
$(function () {
    $('#megaUber').find('a').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

And this bit of CSS needed `actives` changed to `active`

```
.mobile-menu #megaMenu #megaUber > li > ul > li.active > a + ul {
    display: block !important;
}
```

This should nest infinitely.

### Here's what's happening:

The jQuery looks for the list with the right *id*. I took out the other selector text because an *id* should only exist once on a page so there's no need to be more specific in the selector, which is what you were doing. Once it finds that element it looks into all it's children with the `find()` function and attaches `click()` events to all of them. Those click events reference their `parent()` element which goes only one level up, and puts the `active` class on them. That opens your menu.

The `slideToggle` bit just doesn't work like this. If you want that effect you'll have to rethink how the whole thing works. I won't go into that.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with UberMenu, I've never used it. But you must have links in your html, not just `<li>` elements.

Comment: @colpanke thanks for the nice solution but I've still got the problem in my site don't know why but it's still there. let me share my site with you so that you can understand it clearly. I'm testing it for responsive navigation. while opening the menu the first toggle works then clicking on the megaUber a it's working but inside there are more ul li nested these are not working in my site don't know why can u suggest me why it's not working? here's the link of the site: http://www.allwhite3000.co.uk

Comment: Which links have the double submenus?

Comment: They work for me. I'm afraid at this point you're asking for me to debug your site for you and that is not appropriate for this format, not to mention that it's a wordpress and therefor a nightmare to debug without admin access. The problem  is most likely do to some misconfiguration on your part :\ Sorry. You shouldn't have to mess with the javascript at all to do this. My answer is correct for what you actually asked though. I would appreciate you marking it as such.

Comment: sorry for the wrong information it's working actually. but the thing is while opening the other ul from li  you can see that both ul's are open but i want one to be open not all of them that's why i've coded the previous version. do you think you can help me sought that out?

Comment: So you want to have the first sub-menu disappear when you open the second sub-menu?

Comment: What you are attempting is a major change to the functionality of this plugin. You'd be better off finding one that's already designed with this sort of thing in mind. This is a good option, but I've no idea if it's been made into a wp plugin: http://tympanus.net/Development/ResponsiveMultiLevelMenu/

Comment: about this site it's full of unnecessary or necessary js for which responsive uber menu is not working properly also i've tested many other plugins for the responsive one but not working for the theme work. i've just got this issue from my client that's why i've stucked in here. he only want this menu to be there so everything is ok but this is the new problem by clicking the other sub-menu the first one should disable that's the thing should done the work & my query also if it's not bothering you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59534/discussion-between-colepanike-and-tanim).